# dotnet publish only one project from the solution in VSTS

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

We are trying to build one project from a Visual Studio solution in VSTS with [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) task. We are able to "dotnet build" that project. But when we try to "dotnet publish" it tries to publish all projects from the solution. Even if we use "dotnet custom", it tries to publish all projects.

Is there a way to use .NET Core task to publish only one project or projects that were built? Or should we run a custom command line task?

Reason for this is that we have a project that won't build and we don't need/want to publish it. So we would like to build and publish one project and not all projects.

[image: Screenshot from VSTS]

Comment: Can you show the build logs here?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `dotnet publish <Path to .csproj>`. This will build and publish only the specified project and projects it depends on.

In order to specify a project in the '.Net Core' task with the command 'publish' you have to uncheck 'Publish Web Projects'.

Comment: Finally, I did this but with command line task and not .NET Core task. But my question was can I do this with .NET Core task?

Comment: In the '.Net Core' task with the command 'publish' you can specify a path to project(s) if you remove the checkmark 'Publish Web Projects'.
Microsoft has a rudimentary documentation about the VSTS tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core?view=vsts

Comment: Practically that is the answer. So if you can "upgrade" your comment as an answer I can approve it.

Comment: could you please show the settings for other steps too? if you run dotnet publish without specifying any project then it will publish in the default directory but if you have also specified output parameter along with no specific project then it will publish all the projects to same output folder and zip it. when it tries to publish and zip next one then it will clean the publish folder hence only last one remains and your publish artifacts task will publish only one zip file

Answer (score 14):

Another solution would be to set `IsPublishable` in csproj.

I usually do it in cases where it's a unit test project or else that doesn't need to be published if you run `dotnet publish` for solution file.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>

    <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>

    <Configurations>prod;stage;dev</Configurations>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Did you find this documented anywhere?

Comment: yes, on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13365)

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly _documentation_ but it will have to do.

Comment: This is the easiest way to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you un-check the 'Publish Web Projects' you will see a field appear that allows you to enter the project (csproj) you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

This is decided on Project Dependencies for each projects.

In other words, there are some configuration to say that "which project need to build first, in order to let your target project successfully build."

If you are using Visual Studio, right click on solution and click 'Properties'.
In this example, my target run is `TestAngular.Web.Host` and in order to build that projects, it's required to build `TestAngular.Web.Core` first.
[image: Project-Dependencies]

If you are using different IDE, simply locate to your directory, in my case it would be `src\TestAngular.Web.Host` and modify `TestAngular.Web.Host.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
...
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestAngular.Web.Core\TestAngular.Web.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
...
</Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Add or remove which projects are not required here following same syntax

Comment: First this looked promising but unfortunately, this is not the answer. There aren't dependencies that force to build projects that we don't want to be built.
Maybe it is .NET Core task's feature that you can't define csproj which you want to publish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late to the party but in order to have control over what projects to publish, you could unlink the "Path to project(s)" variable (by clicking on "Link settings"). That makes the field editable and you can specify your desired .csproj.

[image: Link settings dialog box]